# Predicted Y2 correlates better with Y1 than Predicted Y1

Tags: regression, correlation, interpretation, model-evaluation

I have a data matrix X of reasonable size (10000, 100), and I am trying to predict targets Y1 and Y2.

B1 = (X^T • X)^-1 (X^T • Y1)

B2 = (X^T • X)^-1 (X^T • Y2)

Pred Y1 = X • B1

Pred Y2 = X • B2

I observe the following:

1. The correlation between Y1 and Y2 is high (0.8),
2. The correlation between Pred Y1 and Y1 is low (0.1),
3. The correlation between Pred Y2 and Y2 is high (0.9),
4. The correlation between Pred Y2 and Y1 is high (0.7).

Therefore, it seems it is better to predict Y2 if we want to know the value Y1? How is it that a regression line not optimized for Y1 performs better on Y1? Can we conclude Pred Y2 is better at predicting Y2 than Pred Y1?

Edit: Please note that Y1 and Y2 are evaluation metrics.

Comment: You cannot make any such conclusions, because they would contradict the optimality of the solutions in the least squares sense: if you were to predict $Y_2$ and throw that into your model as one of the explanatory variables, the resulting model would give *the very same* predictions of $Y_1$ as the original model.

Comment: The "predictions" you gave are actually the expressions for the linear model coefficients, not predicted values.

Comment: Right, I have updated the math. Same question…

Comment: If B3 = (Y2_pred^T • Y2_pred)^-1 (Y2_pred^T • Y1), then Y2_pred • B3 indeed correlates well Y1 (0.8) but has a higher mse of (10) vs the other mse of (1) from X • B1.